# GraphQL: multiply input mutations

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I use my mutation to send one single "create input".
But I need to create a list of 480 objects, maybe in a bulk.

**model (server side):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace GraphQL.Domain.Models
{
    public partial class ShopCreditTransaction
    {
        [Key][Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public string ApiTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
        public string ShopStatus { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
        public decimal OriginalAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal RevokedAmount { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; } //FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES[db_owner].[Currency] (CurrencyID),
        public string ApiCustomerId { get; set; }
        public string ApiCreditAccountId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? ReversalDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? ReversalEntryDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? ReversalBookedDate { get; set; }
        public string Md5Hash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That's the default model (like the DB behind).

**input type (server side):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GraphQL.Domain.InputTypes.ShopCredit
{
    public class CreateShopCreditTransactionInput
    {
        public CreateShopCreditTransactionInput() { }
        public CreateShopCreditTransactionInput(DateTime createdAt, DateTime modifiedAt, string apiTransactionId, string referenceId, string shopStatus, string apiCustomerId, string customerFirstName, string customerLastName, string apiCreditAccountId, decimal currentAmount, decimal originalAmount, decimal revokedAmount, int currencyId, DateTime? orderDate, DateTime? deliveryDate, DateTime? invoiceDate, DateTime? reversalDate, DateTime? reversalEntryDate, DateTime? reversalBookedDate, string md5Hash)
        {
            CreatedAt = createdAt;
            ModifiedAt = modifiedAt;
            ApiTransactionId = apiTransactionId;
            ReferenceId = referenceId;
            ShopStatus = shopStatus;
            ApiCustomerId = apiCustomerId;
            CustomerFirstName = customerFirstName;
            CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
            ApiCreditAccountId = apiCreditAccountId;
            CurrentAmount = currentAmount;
            OriginalAmount = originalAmount;
            RevokedAmount = revokedAmount;
            CurrencyId = currencyId;
            OrderDate = orderDate;
            DeliveryDate = deliveryDate;
            InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
            ReversalDate = reversalDate;
            ReversalEntryDate = reversalEntryDate;
            ReversalBookedDate = reversalBookedDate;
            Md5Hash = md5Hash;
        }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public string ApiTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
        public string ShopStatus { get; set; }
        public string ApiCustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
        public string ApiCreditAccountId { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal OriginalAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal RevokedAmount { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalEntryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalBookedDate { get; set; }
        public string Md5Hash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Only the full input type for a create.

**mutation type (server side):**

```
using GraphQL.Domain.InputTypes.ShopCredit;
using GraphQL.Domain.Models;
using GraphQL.Infra.Data.Context;
using HotChocolate;
using HotChocolate.Data;
using HotChocolate.Types;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GraphQL.API.MutationTypes
{
    [ExtendObjectType("Mutation")]
    public class ShopCreditTransactionMutations : IShopCreditTransactionMutations
    {
        public async Task<ShopCreditTransaction> CreateShopCreditTransaction(CreateShopCreditTransactionInput createShopCreditTransactionInput)
        {
            var context = new ToolsDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext();
            ShopCreditTransaction newTransaction = new ShopCreditTransaction()
            {
                CreatedAt = createShopCreditTransactionInput.CreatedAt,
                ModifiedAt = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ModifiedAt,
                ApiTransactionId = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ApiTransactionId,
                ReferenceId = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ReferenceId,
                ShopStatus = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ShopStatus,
                ApiCustomerId = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ApiCustomerId,
                CustomerFirstName = createShopCreditTransactionInput.CustomerFirstName,
                CustomerLastName = createShopCreditTransactionInput.CustomerLastName,
                ApiCreditAccountId = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ApiCreditAccountId,
                CurrentAmount = createShopCreditTransactionInput.CurrentAmount,
                OriginalAmount = createShopCreditTransactionInput.OriginalAmount,
                RevokedAmount = createShopCreditTransactionInput.RevokedAmount,
                CurrencyId = createShopCreditTransactionInput.CurrencyId,
                OrderDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.OrderDate,
                DeliveryDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.DeliveryDate,
                InvoiceDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.InvoiceDate,
                ReversalDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ReversalDate,
                ReversalEntryDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ReversalEntryDate,
                ReversalBookedDate = createShopCreditTransactionInput.ReversalBookedDate,
                Md5Hash = createShopCreditTransactionInput.Md5Hash,
            };

            var createdTransaction = context.ShopCreditTransactions.Add(newTransaction);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return createdTransaction.Entity;
        }
    }
}
```

The mutation type with embedded input type.

**small entity (client side):**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CommonTemp.Payments.ShopCredit.Models
{
    public class ShopCreditTransactionSyncCheck
    {
        [Key][Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ApiTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ShopStatus { get; set; }
        public string Md5Hash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A small query model (just the important fields).

**input entity (client side):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CommonTemp.Payments.ShopCredit.Models
{
    public class CreateShopCreditTransactionInput
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public string ApiTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
        public string ShopStatus { get; set; }
        public string ApiCustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
        public string ApiCreditAccountId { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal OriginalAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal RevokedAmount { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalEntryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReversalBookedDate { get; set; }
        public string Md5Hash { get; set; }


        public CreateShopCreditTransactionInput() { }

        public CreateShopCreditTransactionInput(DateTime createdAt, DateTime modifiedAt, string apiTransactionId, string referenceId, string shopStatus, string apiCustomerId, string customerFirstName, string customerLastName, string apiCreditAccountId, decimal currentAmount, decimal originalAmount, decimal revokedAmount, int currencyId, DateTime? orderDate, DateTime? deliveryDate, DateTime? invoiceDate, DateTime? reversalDate, DateTime? reversalEntryDate, DateTime? reversalBookedDate, string md5Hash)
        {
            CreatedAt = createdAt;
            ModifiedAt = modifiedAt;
            ApiTransactionId = apiTransactionId;
            ReferenceId = referenceId;
            ShopStatus = shopStatus;
            ApiCustomerId = apiCustomerId;
            CustomerFirstName = customerFirstName;
            CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
            ApiCreditAccountId = apiCreditAccountId;
            CurrentAmount = currentAmount;
            OriginalAmount = originalAmount;
            RevokedAmount = revokedAmount;
            CurrencyId = currencyId;
            OrderDate = orderDate;
            DeliveryDate = deliveryDate;
            InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
            ReversalDate = reversalDate;
            ReversalEntryDate = reversalEntryDate;
            ReversalBookedDate = reversalBookedDate;
            Md5Hash = md5Hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, the full input type on client (for create).

Now I'm using Banana-Cake-Pop to tryout my query strings...

**single create input (client side) - does work:**

```
mutation {
  createShopCreditTransaction(createShopCreditTransactionInput: {
    createdAt: "2017-03-17",
    modifiedAt: "2017-03-17",
    apiTransactionId: "DDDDD",
    referenceId: "-4",
    shopStatus: "LIEFERUNG_MELDEN",
    customerFirstName: "David",
    customerLastName: "Tennant",
    currentAmount: 666.0000,
    originalAmount: 666.0000,
    revokedAmount: 0,
    currencyId: 1,
    apiCustomerId: "-4",
    apiCreditAccountId: "-4",
    orderDate: null,
    deliveryDate: null,
    invoiceDate: null,
    reversalDate: null,
    reversalEntryDate: null,
    reversalBookedDate: null
  })
  {
    id,
    md5Hash
  }
}
```

**mutliply create input (client side) - does *NOT* work:**

```
mutation {
  createShopCreditTransaction(createShopCreditTransactionInput: [
    {
      createdAt: "2021-07-20",
      modifiedAt: "2021-07-20",
      apiTransactionId: "AAAAAA",
      referenceId: "I000457772",
      shopStatus: "LIEFERUNG_MELDEN",
      apiCustomerId: "9423104372",
      customerFirstName: "Ralf",
      customerLastName: "Ratenkauf",
      apiCreditAccountId: "9341040827",
      currentAmount: 100.0000,
      originalAmount: 100.0000,
      revokedAmount: 0.0000,
      currencyId: 1,
      orderDate: "2021-07-16",
      deliveryDate: null,
      invoiceDate: null,
      reversalDate: null,
      reversalEntryDate: null,
      reversalBookedDate: null,
      md5Hash: "f4162b9b7e4636864ad9e3e995108d45"
    },
    {
      createdAt: "2021-07-20",
      modifiedAt: "2021-07-20",
      apiTransactionId: "BBBBBB",
      referenceId: "I000457772",
      shopStatus: "LIEFERUNG_MELDEN",
      apiCustomerId: "9423104372",
      customerFirstName: "Ralf",
      customerLastName: "Ratenkauf",
      apiCreditAccountId: "9341040827",
      currentAmount: 200.0000,
      originalAmount: 200.0000,
      revokedAmount: 0.0000,
      currencyId: 1,
      orderDate: "2021-07-16",
      deliveryDate: null,
      invoiceDate: null,
      reversalDate: null,
      reversalEntryDate: null,
      reversalBookedDate: null,
      md5Hash: "e3162b9b7e4636864ad9e3e995108d46"
    },
    {
      createdAt: "2021-07-20",
      modifiedAt: "2021-07-20",
      apiTransactionId: "CCCCCC",
      referenceId: "I000457772",
      shopStatus: "LIEFERUNG_MELDEN",
      apiCustomerId: "9423104372",
      customerFirstName: "Ralf",
      customerLastName: "Ratenkauf",
      apiCreditAccountId: "9341040827",
      currentAmount: 300.0000,
      originalAmount: 300.0000,
      revokedAmount: 0.0000,
      currencyId: 1,
      orderDate: "2021-07-16",
      deliveryDate: null,
      invoiceDate: null,
      reversalDate: null,
      reversalEntryDate: null,
      reversalBookedDate: null,
      md5Hash: "d2162b9b7e4636864ad9e3e995108d47"
    },
  ])
  {
        id,
        apiTransactionId,
        shopStatus,
        md5Hash
  }
}
```

Do I need to change the server side models (to array/collection)?

Or is my [bulk] syntax wrong? And what will be the right syntax?

Is there a way without using Strawberry Shake (hotchoclate), because I don't have .NET-5 (only 4.xx)?

It's just a cheap shop option, to load transactions by API and check/sync to the database.

Thanks for each help!

Answer (score 1):

I can't really help you with the C# part but in general a mutation input can either be a list or a single item. The funny thing is, that if it is a list, it accepts single items. To illustrate this:

```
type Mutation {
  takesSingle(arg: String!): String
  takesList(arg: [String!]!): String
}

query {
  takesSingle(arg: "x") # works!
  takesSingle(arg: ["x", "x"]) # errors!

  takesList(arg: "x") # works!
  takesList(arg: ["x", "x"]) # works!
}
```

This means there is no bulk operation that can easily be invoked in GraphQL, if you have a single operation. What you can do is adopt your implementation to take a list. The downside is, that you have to design your resolver in a way to handle a list of inputs. Of course this might prove challenging sometimes, but you can get the benefit of bulk inserts e.g. in SQL.

You can also just send 480 http requests like in REST. This might also be fine, or you send batches of 3 (or ten or 20):

```
fragment Response on ShopCreditTransaction {
  id,
  apiTransactionId,
  shopStatus,
  md5Hash
}

mutation batch(
  $first: CreateShopCreditTransactionInput,
  $second: CreateShopCreditTransactionInput,
  $third: CreateShopCreditTransactionInput
) {
  first: createShopCreditTransaction(createShopCreditTransactionInput: $first) {
    ...Response
  }
  second: createShopCreditTransaction(createShopCreditTransactionInput: $second) {
    ...Response
  }
  third: createShopCreditTransaction(createShopCreditTransactionInput: $third) {
    ...Response
  }
}
```

But here, all these inserts are also done sequentially, so there is not much to be gained from this approach in terms of performance or used resources.

Comment: This is very interesting. Okay, I'll look for all my server side mutation types, in future. 
I will tryout today, maybe it works. :) 

Yeah the client side "batch" is only a list of singles, also done sequentially on the server side. This is not what I need. ;) 

But I will look for my server side models and mutation types. 
Thank you very much! :)